# Include config file using url?

Tags: php

I have struggled with including config file in php. i have a config.php file in `TAA/system/application/config` but i need to include that config file to my local.php presented in `TAA/` so i did this but it throw error message.

> 1. http:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by
>      allow_url_include=0
> 2. failed to open stream: no suitable wrapper could be found

i include the config file using `include("http://baseurl/TAA/system/application/config/config.php");`

Comment: what for you want to include a **file** using URL?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't specify the `http:` protocol. That will just make PHP request the file using HTTP. You also have `allow_url_include` disabled in `php.ini`.

Instead, use `include __DIR__ . '/system/application/config.php'`;

If you are using < 5.3, then replace `__DIR__` with `dirname(__FILE__)`.

Comment: i got following error when using your code:  1. failed to open stream:   2. Failed opening  3. Access denied for user 'ODBC'@'localhost' (using password: NO)  4.A link to the server could not be established in